# simplify javascript if statement where conditions are identical except for variable

Tags: javascript, if-statement, simplify

I apologize if this is a duplicate question. It's such a use-case question that it seems everyone has their own version.

I'm wondering if this can be simplified:

```
if ($('.taxclass').text().indexOf(tax1)>-1 || $('.taxclass').text().indexOf(tax2)>-1) {}
```

Comment: absolutly, use pure js instead of jquery, thats a 40-70kb reduce :)

Comment: @Ark doesn't really matter if OP has other jQuery dependencies, which is most likely the case if he is posting jQuery code.

Comment: I can't get over how quickly the answers come on this site. :)

Comment: @FabrícioMatté you're doing a assumption of my assumption, that's a inception :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty simple as it stands, but you could make it a bit less redundant mainly by getting the elements text only once and reusing the variable:

```
var text = $('.taxclass').text();
if (text.indexOf(tax1)>-1 || text.indexOf(tax2)>-1) {

}
```

A further note could be to reduce the traversal of the DOM by using an identifier and looking only for a distinct element (if that suits your needs) instead of every possible thing that has the class `taxclass`.

Comment: Agreed on your note. But I don't have that luxury in this case. Even still, you answered my question and then some.

Answer (score 3):

You can  store `$('.taxclass').text()` in a variable, or use regex.

```
var str = $('.taxclass').text();

if (str.indexOf(tax1) > -1 || str.indexOf(tax2) > -1)

// Or with regex
if(/(text1)|(text2)/.test($('.taxclass').text())
{}
```

Comment: I refuse to believe that regex simplifies this by anyone's standards.

Comment: @GrantThomas, it would if you have more strings to test. You could build you regex from and array.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko, Good point. If this was more complex, that would seem tempting. But is it less efficient?

Answer (score 3):

```
var txt = $('.taxclass').text();
if (txt.indexOf(tax1)>-1 || txt.indexOf(tax2)>-1) {}
```

Comment: That isn't really simplified, it's just more readable. The process is the same.

Answer (score 3):

One super quick way would be not to duplicate $('.taxclass').text()

Try something like

```
var tax = $('.taxclass').text();
if (tax.indexOf(tax1)>-1 || tax.indexOf(tax2)>-1) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty:

```
text.indexOf(tax1+"~"+tax2)>-1
```

Functional, works on *n* strings, but verbose:

```
[tax1, tax2].some(function(s) { return s.indexOf(text)>-1 })
```

As a prototype:

```
String.prototype.foundIn = function() {
    var s=this; return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).some(function(m)
       {return m.indexOf(s)>-1});
};
```

Usage:

```
$('.taxclass').text().foundIn(tax1, tax2)
```

Comment: No. `tax`es are no arrays, they are substrings.

Comment: Interesting method. Although, I wish you had left your original in place. This makes Bergi's comment look misplaced.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
f = function (x) { return $('.taxclass').text().indexOf(x) > -1; }
if (f(tax1) || f(tax2)) {}
```

Comment: This simplifies? What, when it dawns on you that you need to know in a week or two, then, is `f`?

Comment: I don't think it's simpler than alternatives posted, but the asker might.